# Python return multiple values and check for return False

Tags: python, python-3.x

I see plenty of good advice about how to return multiple values in a function, but what's the preferred way to also handle checking other returns like False?

For example:

```
def f():
    if condition1:
        return False
    else:
        return x, y, z

x, y, z = f()
```

I can verify `if [x, y, z] is not None:` but how about also checking for `False`? Is it just `if [x, y, z] is not None and f() is not False:` or is there a superior way?

Comment: As far as I know, a function should always return the same object type (even if it is not required).

Comment: @ettanany No it should not. But it better does.

Comment: That's why I said "even if it is not required", In other programming languages you even mention the return value type in function definition.

Comment: @ettanany In general, this restriction wouldn't help. Suppose the OT function always returns a tuple: `(False,)` in the `True` case and `x,y,z` in the `False` case. Both tuples are "the same object type", but the original program still does not work, because the number of items is different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are in the unfortunate situation where you *must* deal with a function that behaves like the one you presented, a clear way to handle it is with a `try:` statement.

```
try:
    x, y, z = f()
except TypeError:
    <handle the situation where False was returned>
```

This works because trying to unpack `False` raises a `TypeError`.

---

If you *can* modify the function, I might argue that the idiomatic strategy would be to raise an error (either built-in or custom) instead of returning `False`.

```
def f():
    if condition1:
        raise ValueError('Calling f() is invalid because condition1 evaluates to True')
    return x, y, z

try:
    x, y, z = f()
except ValueError:
    <handle the situation where a tuple could not be returned>
```

This has the benefit of showing the true nature of the error in an uncaught traceback rather than the less obvious `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`. It also has the benefit of giving consistent return types, so there is no confusion from the user.

Documentation becomes much clearer as well, because instead of

```
"in the case of success it will return a tuple of three elements, but in the case of failure it will return False (not as a tuple)"
```

the documentation becomes

```
"returns a tuple of three elements; raises a ValueError on failure"
```

Answer (score 13):

I think it'd help to have more consistency:

```
def f():
    if condition1:
        return False, None
    else:
        return True, (x, y, z)

success, tup = f()
if success:
    x, y, z = tup
    # use x, y, z...
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the result to a single variable and check if it's false:

```
retval = f()
if retval != False:
  x,y,z = retval
else: # False
  ...
```

Comment: I downvoted because of the returning three `False`s bit. It is redundant and may add complexity in a case when `x, y, z` each have meaningful boolean values.